# What are some non-standard ways to use namespaces?

Tags: c#, c++, namespaces

I am interested in unprecedented, cool, and esoteric ways to use namespaces.   I know that many advanced developers "hack" namespaces by, for example, using them as references to string constants.  In the string constants example, the idea is to implement DRY (DRY = Do Not Repeat Yourself) and you can keep all your strings in one file.

note: I am looking for answers related to "common" languages such as C#, Ruby, Java, etc.

Comment: So you want to be a developer that does everything differently to everyone else to try and be cool? Do you find it that hard to fit it at the Christmas dinner or something? My advice, DONT. You will just end up annoying your coworkers trying to find code.

Comment: Maybe it's not for real use, but just interest in knowing cool language tricks. Nothing is wrong with that, especially since they can often deepen your understanding of the language.

Comment: I agree with John and assume Rob is being sarcastic.

Answer (score 1):

One esoteric use I often resort to is when defining enums in C++, especially when there are several types in a cetain context. This enables usage such as `Quality::k_high` and `Importance::k_high` in related contexts. Enums also often sport unknown values (usually to represent cases where none have been set), which need to be qualified to disambiguate constants (say, `k_qualityNone` and `k_importanceNone`), which is avoided using namespaces.

A definition will thus look like:

```
namespace Quality {
   enum Type { k_high, k_medium, k_low, k_none };
}
```

and

```
namespace Importance {
   enum Type { k_high, k_medium, k_low, k_none };
}
```

Functions and methods will then take an argument of type `Quality::Type` (and `Importance::Type`), which is rather descriptive and nice. Individual enumeration constants are also qualified similarly as mentioned earlier (`Quality::k_low`).

Comment: I also use and love this technique because it helps self document the code.